# Mustache.js tags left unchanged

Tags: javascript, html, json, mustache

I use Mustache.js in a java web app developed with Play framework. The Mustache templates are loaded from `<script>` tags from an .html file like below. The data for filling in the tags comes from a JSON object.

```
<script id="offerTemplate" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
<div id="{{offer-id}}" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 padding-0 offer-template display-none" style="max-height:331px; overflow:hidden;">
    <a href="/offerDetails/{{search-id}}/{{query}}/{{offer-id}}" style="display: block; margin: 0 5px 10px; max-height:321px; overflow:hidden;">
...
```

For some reason, sometimes Mustache doesn't replace the tags in the template. I noticed in the app logs that users sometimes click on links containing tags like `.../offerDetails/{{search-id}}/{{query}}/{{offer-id}}..` and the only explanation for this is that Mustache leaves the tags as they are. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the problem.

Is there any known case for which Mustache.js leaves tags as they are? My assumption is that there is a problem with the JSON object that I pass to Mustache that causes this behavior.

Comment: How are you passing the JSON object? Is it a REST call? If so you can verify logs for the REST calls of these users.

Comment: I tried to check whether the resulting html produced by Mustache.render() contains any templates (like "{{...}}"), but I couldn't catch any issues. My assumption for now is that some browsers look into the templates file (which is an .html file) and try to prefetch the templated links.